# Deployment Issue in nextjs app path error

Tags: docker, npm, error-handling, deployment

I was working on a NextJS project, and it is perfectly running, build has no issues, no issues when running on docker. Deployed on vercel, and it's working fine. But during hosting, it's having issues

```
npm ERR! path /app
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! signal SIGKILL
npm ERR! command sh -c next start
```

[image]
Here is my docker file:

```
FROM node:20-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm","run", "start"]
```

can someone please help me solve the issue

I have tried checking changing the work dir, and checked on multiple os locally everything's working fine, but it's having issues in hosting.

Comment: Have you took a look into the mentioned logfile?